# GridView filter model in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, gridview, yii2

I have a gridview with a dataprovider which has joined two tables as query:

```
 $applicationDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => Application::find()->with('applicantInfo')
                    ->where(['job_posting_id' => $jobPosting->id,
                        'deleted_flag' => 0])->orderBy('created_at desc'),
                'pagination' => [
                    'pageSize' => 5
                ]
            ]);
```

and here is my `GridView`:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $applicationDataProvider,
                'filterModel'=>$searchModel,
                'columns' => [
                    'id',
                    [
                        'class' => yii\grid\DataColumn::className(),
                        'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'color:#337ab7'],
                        'header' => 'სახელი',
                        'label'=>'name',
                        'value' => function ($data) {
                            return $data->applicantInfo->first_name . ' ' . $data->applicantInfo->last_name;
                        }
                    ],


                    'applicantInfo.email',
                    'applicantInfo.phone',
                    'created_at:date',
                    [
                        'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                        'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'color:#337ab7'],
                        'template' => '{view}',
                        'buttons' => [
                            'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                                return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', $url, [
                                    'title' => Yii::t('app', 'გახსნა'),
                                ]);
                            }


                        ],
                        'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                            if ($action === 'view') {
                                $url = '/app-info/?id=' . $model->id;
                                return $url;
                            }

                        }

 ...
```

in a *search model* I have **email** field only because I want to gridview has just only email search field.

```
class ApplicationSearch extends Application
{


    public function rules()
    {
        return [

            [['email'], 'safe'],
            ];
    }
```

but here is not drawn search field for email, how can I fix it?

Comment: is `email` a part of your table schema means is it an actual field? or a public attribute only for the model?

Comment: it is a column of applicant_info table but not of application

Comment: the answer given below should work in that case isnt it working for you?

Comment: no, it didn't work. . .

Comment: look, I updated my question and added columns in my snippet of code, maybe it helps you to answer

Comment: ok where have you defined `$applicationDataProvider` , inside the `ApplicationSearch` model `search()` function ?

Comment: yes, I defined it in ApplicationSearch model

Comment: the answers below should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `email` attribute to `ApplicationSearch` to store value from filter:

```
class ApplicationSearch extends Application {

    public $email;

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['email'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Use this attribute for filtering:

```
$applicationDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Application::find()->with('applicantInfo')
        ->where(['job_posting_id' => $jobPosting->id, 'deleted_flag' => 0])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'applicantInfo.email', $this->email])
        ->orderBy('created_at desc'),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 5
    ]
]);
```

And use value from relation in grid:

```
// ...
[
    'attribute' => 'email',
    'value' => function ($data) {
        return $data->applicantInfo->email;
    },
],
'applicantInfo.phone',
// ...
```

Comment: got an error: "Setting unknown property: yii\grid\DataColumn::name"

Comment: should be `attriibute`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yeah, just fixed it. **@godot** try updated version.

Comment: this answer should work as it includes the related record filter for the search too.